# Difference between autoplay & autostart

Tags: html, video, autoplay, autostart

Can someone tell me what is the difference between those two attributes:

- Autoplay
- Autostart

If I understand well, "Autoplay" means that the video will automatically start playing when it is possible.

Thank you,
Léa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like "autostart" in W3C standards.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me. You're right. By the way, I'm working with video.js, and I found this attribute in 2.0 version. So, I can delete it now that I know it's useless.